# Setting the value of a class property via method

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, properties, instance-variables

So, I have been trying to implement the following:

```
from abc import ABC
from abc import abstractmethod

class parent(ABC):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def example_variable(self)->str:
        ...
        
    @abstractmethod
    def example_method(self)->int:
        ...
        
    def __init__(self, foo: int):
        self.foo = foo
        
class child(parent):
    def example_method(self)->int:
        return self.foo + 10
    
    example_variable = f"This is example variable of value {self.example_method()}"
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    example_object = child(59)
    print(example_object.example_variable)
```

As you can see, I have created an abstract class with an abstract property and method, and I have tried to implement the child class by using the value of an instance variable to compute a simple value and using that value to set the value of a property using an F string.

But the difficulty is that the interpreter for some reason does not recognise the self reference for the `example_method()`:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [7], line 17
     14     def __init__(self, foo: int):
     15         self.foo = foo
---> 17 class child(parent):
     18     def example_method(self)->int:
     19         return self.foo + 10

Cell In [7], line 21, in child()
     18 def example_method(self)->int:
     19     return self.foo + 10
---> 21 example_variable = f"This is example variable of value {self.example_method()}"

NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

And I have been trying to figure this out, without success.

I tried removing the `self` reference:

```
example_variable = f"This is example variable of value {example_method()}"
```

But then it throws the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [10], line 17
     14     def __init__(self, foo: int):
     15         self.foo = foo
---> 17 class child(parent):
     18     def example_variable(self)->int:
     19         return self.foo + 10

Cell In [10], line 21, in child()
     18 def example_variable(self)->int:
     19     return self.foo + 10
---> 21 example_variable = f"This is example variable of value {example_method()}"

NameError: name 'example_method' is not defined
```

My question is, why doesn't the python interpreter evaluate the self reference correctly? Has the method been not instantiated yet? If so, then what is the correct way to instantiate the `example_method()`?

Comment: What should `self` even refer to here? You're defining a class attribute with `example_variable = ...`, so?? Please clarify what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'self' argument is only recognized within a class method as it is passed as an argument to the method. (By default, the first argument of a Python class method is a pointer to the class) The example_variable in the above case is being defined outside the method, hence, using self.example_method() will be incorrect.

Secondly, if you are inheriting a parent class within a child class, it must first be initialized with super().__init__() for its methods to be recognized.

My suggestion will be to define example_variable locally within the constructor of the child class or through another method.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that your problem lies in the fact that what you want is example_variable to be a variable defined during init, so define it in `__init__`.
However, doing so I'm not sure that example_variable won't be fixated with the value of example_method during init; if you want example_variable to change in case the result of example_method changes, then example_variable should probably stay a @property function, just the same way you defined it in your parent class.